# Ionic: First time page is loaded videoplayer works, after navigating back video player is not being displayed

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm working with Ionic and I'm using a the Ooyala video player, the first time the page is loaded everything works fine. But when I go to another page and then navigate back with the browser back button, the video is not being displayed. If I click on a button that plays the video, even if the video is not being displayed, the video is played. I can hear the sound of the video.

Comment: Please add some code How you are playing video in your Screen and where you putted that code.

Comment: in ngOnDestroy, you can destroy the video instance by setting null.